# How do I make my health bar decrease based on damage received?

Tags: javascript, sketch.js

So basically I'm trying to create a shooter game. But a problem arose while trying to implement a health bar function for the player. Although I did manage to create a health bar that reduces or decreases based on its value, I can't change its value via code. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have created a player and enemy sprite who constantly shoot bullet sprites at each other. I am trying to make the player sprite's health bar go down when the enemy sprite's bullet (bullet_e) makes contact with it.

I'm considerably new to JavaScript, so please forgive any rookie mistakes.

Here's the script (I pasted the entire code, in case putting parts of the code cause problems):

```
var bg;
var player, playerImg;
var bullet_e, bulletImg;
var missile, missile_e, missileImg, missile_e_img;
var fireBall, fireBall_img;

var bg;

var enemy, enemyImg;

var trig1, trig2;

var health = 100;
var maxHealth = 100;

function preload() {
  playerImg = loadImage("Assets/TBM-3.png");
  bulletImg = loadImage("Assets/Bullets_01.png");
  missileImg = loadImage("Assets/missile_01.png");
  missile_e_img = loadImage("Assets/missile_02.png");
  fireBall_img = loadImage("Assets/fireBall_01.png");

  bg = loadImage("Assets/Backgrounds/BG_07.png");

  enemyImg = loadImage("Assets/Enemy_FighterJet_Ba.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  player = createSprite(width / 2, height / 2 + 270);
  player.addImage("player", playerImg);
  player.scale = 0.5;

  enemy = createSprite(windowWidth / 2 + 600, windowHeight / 2 - 300);
  enemy.addImage("enemy", enemyImg);
  enemy.scale = 0.6;

  trig1 = createSprite(windowWidth, windowHeight - 650);
  trig1.scale = 0.7;
  trig1.visible = false;

  trig2 = createSprite(windowWidth / 100, windowHeight - 650);
  trig2.scale = 0.7;
  trig2.visible = false;
}

function draw() {
  background(bg, windowWidth, windowHeight);

  //Health Bar

  playerController();

  enemyController();

  //spawnBullets_p()
  spawnBullets_e();
  //checkCollisions()

  updateHealth();

  drawSprites();
}

function playerController() {
  // Locomotion

  if (keyDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    player.x = player.x + 8;
  }

  if (keyDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    player.x = player.x - 8;
  }

  if (keyDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    player.y = player.y - 6;
  }

  if (keyDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    player.y = player.y + 6;
  }

  //Attacks

  if (keyWentDown("space")) {
    // Right wing
    missile = createSprite(player.x + 39, player.y - 29);
    missile.addImage("missile", missileImg);
    missile.scale = 0.08;
    missile.velocityY = -8;
    missile.lifetime = 80;

    // Left Wing
    missile = createSprite(player.x - 39, player.y - 29);
    missile.addImage("missile", missileImg);
    missile.scale = 0.08;
    missile.velocityY = -8;
    missile.lifetime = 80;
  }
}

function spawnBullets_p() {
  if (frameCount % 4 === 0) {
    bullet_p = createSprite(player.x + 37, player.y - 29);
    bullet_p.addImage("bullet", bulletImg);
    bullet_p.scale = 0.09;
    bullet_p.velocityY = -30;
    bullet_p.lifetime = 30;

    bullet_p = createSprite(player.x - 37, player.y - 29);
    bullet_p.addImage("bullet", bulletImg);
    bullet_p.scale = 0.09;
    bullet_p.velocityY = -30;
    bullet_p.lifetime = 30;
  }
}

function spawnBullets_e() {
  if (frameCount % 6 === 0) {
    bullet_e = createSprite(enemy.x + 33, enemy.y + 68);
    bullet_e.addImage("bullet", bulletImg);
    bullet_e.scale = 0.09;
    bullet_e.velocityY = 30;
    bullet_e.lifetime = 30;

    bullet_e = createSprite(enemy.x - 33, enemy.y + 68);
    bullet_e.addImage("bullet", bulletImg);
    bullet_e.scale = 0.09;
    bullet_e.velocityY = 30;
    bullet_e.lifetime = 30;

    if (bullet_e.isTouching(player)) {
      health = health - 5;
      bullet_e.destroyed();
    }

    console.log(health);
  }
}

function enemyController() {
  // locomotion

  if (enemy.isTouching(trig1)) {
    enemy.velocityX = -4;
  }

  if (enemy.isTouching(trig2)) {
    enemy.velocityX = 4;
  }

  //Attack

  if (frameCount % 100 === 0) {
    // Right wing
    missile_e = createSprite(enemy.x + 50, enemy.y + 68);
    missile_e.addImage("missile2", missile_e_img);
    missile_e.scale = 0.08;
    missile_e.velocityY = +8;
    missile_e.lifetime = 80;

    // Left Wing
    missile_e = createSprite(enemy.x - 50, enemy.y + 68);
    missile_e.addImage("missile2", missile_e_img);
    missile_e.scale = 0.08;
    missile_e.velocityY = +8;
    missile_e.lifetime = 80;
  }

  if (frameCount % 300 === 0) {
    fireBall = createSprite(enemy.x, enemy.y + 30);
    fireBall.addImage("fireBall", fireBall_img);
    fireBall.scale = 0.09;
    fireBall.velocityY = 5;
    fireBall.lifetime = 90;
  }
}

function checkCollisions() {
  if (bullet_e.isTouching(player)) {
    health = -5;
  }
}

function updateHealth() {
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  noFill();
  rect(10, 10, 200, 20);

  noStroke();
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(10, 10, map(health, 0, maxHealth, 0, 200), 20);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting anything when your bullet is colliding with the player? I see you have a console.log() that logs your health, what are you getting there when the collision happens?

Comment: Nothing happens. The value is stuck on whatever value I put in the global variable

Answer (score 1):

i see your code and in this function

```
function checkCollisions() 
{
  if(bullet_e.isTouching(player))
  {
    health = -5;
  }
}
```

the health variable is change to a value of -5 instead of decreasing that should be 95 and so on. Try this

```
function checkCollisions() 
{
  if(bullet_e.isTouching(player))
  {
    health -=5;
  }
}
```

or health = health -5;

---

if the value still not changing. Try to put `console.log("function name")` to your functions to know if its called or not. Sometimes troubles are hidden on logical statements that hard to notice that the values or the condition dint meet properly.

Comment: In that case, it straight up gives an error that "isTouching" is  undefined, hence can't read it's property

Comment: in this link forum.code.org/t/istouching-not-working/32609 it said that you should check if the bullet and the player sprites are created first before using the collision function.

you should draw each sprites first before you can do a collision detection

Comment: I created the player in function Setup(), the bullet gets created in the function spawnBullets_e()

Comment: And both of them are above function checkCollisions() :/